# Что не так в скрипте бана?

Tags: html, php

Написал такой вот скрипт, но все равно, что-то не так, идея в том, что если записи IP еще нет такой, какой IP у пользователя, то идёт запись его IP в файл и все. Если же IP в файле нет, то производится запись. Это для определения количества зашедших на сайт пользователей без повторений.

```
<?php 
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$fh1 = fopen("bd/ips.dat", "a"); 
$countip = file("bd/ips.dat");

$count = count($countip);

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)  { 
    echo $countip[$i]."<br>";

    if ($ip == ($countip[$i]))  { 
        die("<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <title>Тест</title> </head> <body> <div class=\"count\">Сюда уже зашли $count раз</div> </body> </html> "); 
    }
}

fwrite($fh1, "$ip\n"); 
fclose($fh1);

echo "<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <title>Тест</title> </head> <body> <div class=\"count\">Сюда уже зашли $count раз</div> </body> </html>"; ?>
```

Comment: Отформатируйте код пожалуйста. Ничего непонятно :(

Comment: простите, я б с радостью, но вставляю текст, выделяю, нажимаю на скобочки, а он текст не форматирует, и так постоянно можно сказать...

Comment: А что не работает хоть скажите?

Comment: $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$fh = fopen("bd/ips.dat", "a");
$countip = file("bd/ips.dat");
$count = count($countip);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
if ($ip == ($countip[$i])) {
ничего не делать
}}
вывести остальной код, если IP нет в списке

Answer (score 1):

измените на if($ip == rtrim($count[$i])) 
равенство никогда не сработает из-за '\n'.
выучите foreach.

и в общем деревенский подход. под большим наплывом пользователей ляжет.

Answer (score 0):

**Вариант 1**

```
 <?php
    $filename='data/ip.txt';
    $IPs=(array)@file($filename);
    $c=count($IPs);
    if (!in_array ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $IPs)) {
         file_put_contents($filename,$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\r\n",FILE_APPEND);
         $c++;
    }
    echo 'Сюда уже зашли '.$c'. раз';
    ?>
```

**Вариант 2**

```
<?=eval('$IPs=(array)@file(\'ip.txt\');$c=count($IPs);if (!in_array ($_SERVER[\'REMOTE_ADDR\'], $IPs)) {file_put_contents(\'ip.txt\',$_SERVER[\'REMOTE_ADDR\']."\r\n",FILE_APPEND);$c++;}return \'Сюда уже зашли \'.$c\'. раз\';');?>
```

**Вариант 3**

```
<?=eval(base64_decode('JElQcz0oYXJyYXkpQGZpbGUoJ2lwLnR4dCcpOyRjPWNvdW50KCRJUHMpO2lmIChpbl9hcnJheSAoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1JFTU9URV9BRERSJ10sICRJUHMpKSB7ZmlsZV9wdXRfY29udGVudHMoJ2lwLnR4dCcsJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1JFTU9URV9BRERSJ10uIlxyXG4iLEZJTEVfQVBQRU5EKTskYysrO31yZXR1cm4gJyYjMTA1NzsmIzExMDI7JiMxMDc2OyYjMTA3MjsgJiMxMDkxOyYjMTA3ODsmIzEwNzc7ICYjMTA3OTsmIzEwNzI7JiMxMDk2OyYjMTA4MzsmIzEwODA7ICcuJGMnLiAmIzEwODg7JiMxMDcyOyYjMTA3OTsnOw=='));?>
```

Comment: Вы второй вариант по приколу сделали?